# Base URL for React.js website on Github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am deploying my portfolio website, made using React.js on Github pages.

All the tutorials mention the following url as the url to the homepage:

```
{
  ...
  "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app",
  ...
}
```

So to open the website, the url would be https://myusername.github.io/my-app. Is it possible to somehow rename the url to only https://myusername.github.io/ as is possible while deploying using pure JavaScript?

I have tried

```
{
  ...
  "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/",
  ...
}
```

already. It only renders the README.md.

Links: https://github.com/Shubhayu-Das/portfolio & https://github.com/Shubhayu-Das/Shubhayu-Das.github.io

Edit: I am using gh-pages to build and deploy the app to Github Pages.

Comment: You'd need an `index.html`. That's the only requirement, like most websites.

Comment: I do have an index.html. I'll add the links to the project in the question. However, npm run build packages everything into chunks, with no discernable index.js

Comment: What is your actual repository? Because `https://github.com/yourusername/some-repo` is assigned `https://yourusername.github.io/some-repo`, and only `https://github.com/yourusername/yourusername.github.io` (so a *repository* that has *the same name* as your username's io url) gets served as purely `https://yourusername.github.io`. So: is this a normal repo? If so, then no, you can't get rid of that `my-app` part: that's literally what _has_ to be there in order for github to serve files from that git repo as if they're normal files. Also see https://guides.github.com/features/pages/

Comment: @Shubhayu Check out my answer, I believe your CI is deploying it from `master` branch but it has to deploy from `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: @Shubhayu you seem to have deployed `https://github.com/Shubhayu-Das/Shubhayu-Das.github.io` from `master` branch.

Comment: Yes I have. The build command creates and updates the gh-pages branch, which is the build branch. It is from this branch that the website is deployed onto GitHub pages

Comment: @Mike I am using React to design my own templates. The two links are two separate repos, one with the homepage set to https://username.github.io/portfolio and the other to https://username.github.io respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to exactly what I was seeking in the following post
https://medium.com/@hannawerman/deploy-your-react-app-on-github-pages-a1d4cfdc88e9

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a common issue. I believe your CI is deploying it from `master` branch but it has to deploy from `gh-pages` branch. In your [**Project Settings**](https://github.com/Shubhayu-Das/portfolio/settings), you have to select the right branch. Currently, I believe it should be something like this:

[image: current]

But you should be using the `gh-pages` branch or upload the `build` directory contents to a directory called `docs` and use the right option like this:

[image: right option]

Hope this helps you to locate the problem and solve it.

Comment: Um, no. It is correctly deployed from the gh-pages branch, as is the default while using Travis(and also gh-pages).

Comment: @Shubhayu [Shubhayu Das](https://shubhayu-das.github.io/portfolio/) works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I forked your repo and rebuilt and redeployed your project and it seem to have fixed the problem for me.

These are the commands I used after forking and cloning:

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run build`
3. `npm run deploy`

Also I had to change the `homepage` attribute according to my repository, but you don't need to do it.

You can check out at: https://github.com/AdityaSrivast/Shubhayu-Das.github.io

Hope it helps!

Comment: First, thanks a lot for you effort! And no, the problem is exactly where you made the changes. The thing is https://username.github.io/ can be used to deploy the website only when the build version exists on the master branch. See the solution that I found, for further clarity. Again, thank you.